# OpenStack: Exception when adding a new nova-compute node

Tags: openstack

I'm trying to add a new nova-compute node (KUubuntu 12.04) to my single node OpenStack (Essex release) installation running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. However, I am getting the following error:-

```
2012-06-22 14:05:12 INFO nova.rpc.common [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2012-06-22 14:05:12 ERROR nova.rpc.common [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 27 seconds.
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common Traceback (most recent call last):
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/rpc/impl_kombu.py", line 446, in reconnect
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common     self._connect()
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/rpc/impl_kombu.py", line 423, in _connect
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common     self.connection.connect()
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 154, in connect
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common     return self.connection
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 560, in connection
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common     self._connection = self._establish_connection()
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 521, in _establish_connection
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common     conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqplib.py", line 255, in establish_connection
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common     connect_timeout=conninfo.connect_timeout)
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqplib.py", line 52, in __init__
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/connection.py", line 129, in __init__
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common     self.transport = create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/transport.py", line 281, in create_transport
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common     return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/transport.py", line 85, in __init__
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common     raise socket.error, msg
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common error: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED
2012-06-22 14:05:12 TRACE nova.rpc.common
```

What is the cause of error and how to fix this error?

Comment: I found the solution. You need to add --rabbit_host=CC_ADDR to /etc/nova/nova.conf on the new node you are adding to the cluster. CC_ADDR is the ip of the cloud controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, you configuration was missing the --rabbit_host = ... flag, which indicates where to find the RabbitMQ service for your OpenStack cloud. The default value is localhost.

Other rabbit flags that nova accepts:

```
--rabbit_host=...
--rabbit_port=...
--rabbit_virtual_host=/
--rabbit_use_ssl
--rabbit_userid=...
--rabbit_password=...
```

Comment: When I gave the "--" before `rabbit_host` it started working. What is the purpose of those "--"?

Comment: it's just the mechanism/convention for complex arguments that openstack uses. Fairly standard for complex optional arguments.

Comment: I don't see the "--" in the official documentation: http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/admin/content/sample-nova-configuration-files.html , what is the exact purpose/ source of this "--"?